# Problema con innerHTML

Tags: javascript

Quiero reemplazar el texto de un elemento html que contiene un link, al que le incorporé su correspondiente ID:

Este código funciona (sin el link):

```
<script>
var titleChange = document.getElementById("navceth").innerHTML = "<a>CETH</a>";
</script>
```

---

Pero cuando incorporo el link dentro del innerHTML a reemplazar, no funciona.

---

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: cual es el elemento html_?

Comment: qué te aparece cuando intentas meter un link mediante innerHTML?

Comment: y también ¿Cómo es la sentencia donde intentas meter el link?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Mi elemento html es: <li id="navceth"><a href="ceth.html">Centro de Estudios en Tecnología del Hormigón</a></li>

Comment: Código con link: <script>
        var titleChange = document.getElementById("navceth").innerHTML = "<a href="ceth.html">CETH</a>";
      </script>

Comment: Este último no cambia nada. Queda el contenido original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trata asi :

```
<script>
var titleChange = document.getElementById("navceth").innerHTML = "<li id=\"navceth\"><a href=\"ceth.html\">Centro de Estudios en Tecnología del Hormigón<\/a><\/li>";
</script>
```

Comment: Genial!!! Gracias Mario! Qué explicación tiene?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character

Comment: Material de estudio. Nuevamente gracias.

Comment: tenías que escapar las comillas dobles o bien usar comillas simples. Por eso te preguntaba cual era exactamente tu sentencia.